# mapbox-gl js use step ramp for "text-offset"

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl, mapbox-marker

I'm using in a mapbox gl layer in the `layout`-block the field `text-offset`.

```
layout: { // Working
  'text-field': '{point_count_abbreviated}',
  'text-size': ['step', ['get', 'point_count'], 18, 10, 14, 100, 12],
  'text-offset': [-0.84, 0.23],
}
```

This is working as expected, but now I want to change the the offset based on a properties. This is working quite well for the `'text-size'`, but for the text-offset I can't find the right syntax. I've tried the following:

```
layout: { // NOT working
  'text-field': '{point_count_abbreviated}',
  'text-size': ['step', ['get', 'point_count'], 18, 10, 14, 100, 12],
  'text-offset': [
    // [-0.84, 0.23],
    ['step', ['get', 'point_count'], -0.84, 10, -0.94, 100, -0.99],
    ['step', ['get', 'point_count'], 0.23, 10, 0.25, 100, 0.28],
  ],
},
```

Maybe mapbox-gl isn't supporting a step ramp at the text-offset at the moment?

Error Message:

> Error: layers.cluster-offline.layout.text-offset[0]: number expected, array found

---

```
layout: { // NOT working
  'text-field': '{point_count_abbreviated}',
  'text-size': ['step', ['get', 'point_count'], 18, 10, 14, 100, 12],
  'text-offset': [
    // [-0.84, 0.23],
    ['literal', 
       ['step', ['get', 'point_count'], -0.84, 10, -0.94, 100, -0.99], 
       ['step', ['get', 'point_count'], 0.23, 10, 0.25, 100, 0.28]
    ],
  ],
},
```

Error Message:

> Error: layers.cluster-offline.layout.text-offset: array length 2 expected, length 1 found

---

```
layout: { // NOT working
  'text-field': '{point_count_abbreviated}',
  'text-size': ['step', ['get', 'point_count'], 18, 10, 14, 100, 12],
  'text-offset': [
    ['literal', ['step', ['get', 'point_count'], -0.84, 10, -0.94, 100, -0.99]], 
    ['literal', ['step', ['get', 'point_count'], 0.23, 10, 0.25, 100, 0.28]],
  ],
},
```

Error Message:

> Error: layers.cluster-offline.layout.text-offset[0]: number expected, array found

Comment: It should work - data-driven styling is supported for text-offset. In your code you don't include a `text-field` though.

Comment: I updated the code above, the field was there before. It's still not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap your text-offset values with a *literal type* converter:

```
'text-offset': [
  'step',                         // Expression type (discrete matching)
  ['get', 'point_count'],         // Variable to compare to
  ['literal', [-0.84, 0.23]],     // Default value (if none of the following match)
  10, ['literal', [-0.94, 0.25]], // if point_count === 10: [-0.94, 0.25]
  100, ['literal', [-0.99, 0.28]] // if point_count === 100: [-0.94, 0.28]
]
```

> Stop output values must be literal values (i.e. not functions or expressions)

[source](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec#function-stops)

Here, the `[-0.84, 0.23]` sub-expressions may be ambiguous to Mapbox, so you need to explicitly tell their type.

Comment: I've tried your code and get the following error: Error: layers.cluster-offline.layout.text-offset: array length 2 expected, length 1 found. I've also updated the code above with two additional tests. Both not working.

Comment: Maybe I nested the 'literal' 1 array too deep. What happens when you put `'text-offset': ['literal', ['step', ...], ['step',...]]` ?

Comment: I've also tried this, but the Error was: "Literal just takes one argument"

Comment: I edited my answer, I think it makes more sense with this syntax

Answer (score 0):

In version `1.6.1`,I have not tested other versions.

you only need to set an array in `properties`,

such as `"offsetdate": [-1,0]`,

and then use `"text-offset": ['get', 'offsetdate']` to get the data .